# JQL: filter comments made after status changed

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, issue-tracking, jql

I need a JQL query to filter all tickets for which comments have been made AFTER their status had been changed to 'Resolved'. All the commands I've found relate to comments made in relation to a particular date (after, before). Is there any way to filter by a sequence of events?
Pseudocode:

```
project in ("project X") 
    AND issuetype = bug 
    AND status in (Resolved) 
    AND issueFunction in commented("after (status changed to 'Resolved')")
```